# How to close modal when navigating back to my screen?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, modal-dialog, use-effect, use-state

So I have a homescreen that renders a modal component. I use some states for modal visibility. However, the problem is that when I navigate from the modal to another screen and then back to my home screen, the modal is still opened and I cannot figure out how to close it. I tried using useEffect but it does not do anything. Any tips?

This is home screen.
The AddButton component is a simple TouchableOpacity that onPress call the toggleModal function

```
const [isModalVisible, setIsModalVisible] = useState(false);

 const toggleModal = () => {
      setIsModalVisible(!isModalVisible);
  };

useEffect(() => {
    setIsModalVisible(false)
  }, [navigation])

return (
    <AddButton
      title="ADD BOOK"
      toggleModal={toggleModal}
    />
)
```

And the Modal Component is this:

```
const ModalComponent = ({navigation, isModalVisible, toggleModal, title, author, save, onNavigate }) => {
  
  return (
    <Modal isVisible={isModalVisible}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Modal</Text>

        <View style={styles.footer}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={toggleModal}>
            <Text>Cancel</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>

          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("AddBookScreen")}>
            <Text>{save}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        
      </View>
    </Modal>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify this code

```
 <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("AddBookScreen")}>
            <Text>{save}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
```

to

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
    navigation.navigate("AddBookScreen")
    toggleModal();
  }}>
            <Text>{save}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: So you are right, I tried this method before put i didn't use () in toggle modal. Thank you so much, I always mess up at simple things

Answer (score 0):

extract onPress function and move it up to your page and pass it as onSaveClick callback to the modal component.

```js
// on your page
const onSaveClick = () => {
  navigation.navigate("AddBookScreen")
  setIsModalVisible(false)
}
```

then in the modal

```html
<TouchableOpacity onPress={onSaveClick}>
  <Text>{save}</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```